# ASP.NET client side validation with dataannotations - javascript minimumlength zero

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm doing client side validation on a project I'm working on. Everything works, except for the minimumlength property of the StringLength attribute (it works when submitting and a serverside validation is done):

```
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6)]
```

The javascript generated by `Html.EnableClientValication();` is the following:

```
// snip 
{"FieldName":"User.Password","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"User_Password_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"The field Password must be a string with a minimum length of 6 and a maximum length of 50.","ValidationParameters":{"minimumLength":0,"maximumLength":50},"ValidationType":"stringLength"}]}],"FormId":"form0","ReplaceValidationSummary":false})
```

The important thing is here:

```
{"minimumLength":0,"maximumLength":50}
```

It produces javascript with the wrong minimumproperty. You guys have a hint? Is this a possible bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the code from reflector

```
    public class StringLengthAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<StringLengthAttribute>
    {
        // Methods
        public StringLengthAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, StringLengthAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
           return new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule[] 
{ new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(base.ErrorMessage, 
-> 0 <-, base.Attribute.MaximumLength) };
        }
    }
```

yea, this is a quite not right.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for verifying this as a bug. Where did you find the source? I've looked aspnet.codeplex.com, but didn't find it.

Comment: Good old Reflector - free tool to disassemble code from .net dll. Very useful.